# Python extract a part of a json element

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have this json response:

`"dataDeNascimento":"1980-03-30T00:00:00",`

What i need is to the response be like this:

30/03/1980

The part of my code how represente this json:

```
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        resp_json2 = response.json()
        nascimento = resp_json2['dataDeNacimento']
```

If you guys can help me i appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime` from `datetime` module to convert your date string into datetime object then reconvert it into your desired date string again.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime


date_ = "1980-03-30T00:00:00" 
new_date = datetime.strptime(date_, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(new_date)
```

Output:

```
30/03/1980
```

Edit:

As @Mark Meyer suggested and if you're using `Python >= 3.7` your can use [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat)

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that you can use `datetime.fromisoformat(date_)` here, which might be easier on the eyes.

Answer (score -1):

You can chop up your string nascimento like this:

```
nascimento = resp_json2['dataDeNacimento'][:10]
```

Which will give you the first 10 characters as a string.

```
"1980-03-30"
```

Comment: `What i need is to the response be like this: 30/03/1980`